# How to pull out the item and subitems of the listview selected entry

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I would like to edit a listview item consisting of 2 ints and 3 strings. I am saving the items to the listview from a public class, "Rineitem". I can assign the selected row to an object and see it in my locals window but I don't know how to get to it, or the subitems of it.

I've tried to find examples but found nothing that is as simple as this should be. My own attempts have often given messages that perhaps I am forgetting a cast to !??? If I convert the object to string I get a text naming the public class.

```
object item = lvw_Smd_Jobs.SelectedItem;
```

When I try to assign the lvw selectedItem to the class I get, Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Rin...Auftrag_Verwalter.Rineitem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
I would like to save two of the string values to textboxes where the user can change the value(s) and then I would save the listview item with it's changes.

Comment: You can bind selecteditem to a public property of type rineitem. If you want to do something when selection changes then act in the setter. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

Comment: Have you tried Rin...Auftrag_Verwalter.Rineitem item = lvw_Smd_Jobs.SelectedItem; ?

Answer (score 0):

One, why not save all items as strings, that way your casting is simplified.

Then to remove a selected item. You'd do the following

var item = (string)lvw_Smd_Jobs.SelectedItem;
lvw_Smd_Jobs.Items.Remove(item);

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a "ListBoxItem" (type object) to the class it realy is.

Here a little example how to add, read and modify items in your `ListBox`:

```
// Example class
public class RineItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Override ToString() for correct displaying in listbox
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name: " + this.Name;
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Adding some examples to our empty box
    this.ListBox1.Items.Add(new RineItem() { Name = "a", Id = 1 });
    this.ListBox1.Items.Add(new RineItem() { Name = "b", Id = 2 });
    this.ListBox1.Items.Add(new RineItem() { Name = "c", Id = 3 });
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Loop through SelectedItems
    foreach (var item in this.ListBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        // Have a look at it's type. It is our class!
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + item.GetType()); 
        // We cast to the desired type
        RineItem ri = item as RineItem;
        // And we got our instance in our type and are able to work with it.
        Console.WriteLine("RineItem: " + ri.Name + ", " + ri.Id); 

        // Let's modify it a little
        ri.Name += ri.Name;
        // Don't forget to Refresh the items, to see the new values on screen
        this.ListBox1.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

The Error-Message you're facing tells you, that there is no implicit cast to convert an `object` to and RineItem.

There are implicit cast possible (From int to long). And you can create you own ones. Here an example:

```
public class RineItem2
{
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public int Id2 { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator RineItem(RineItem2 o)
    {
        return new RineItem() { Id = o.Id2, Name = o.Name2 };
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
RineItem2 r2 = new RineItem2();
RineItem r = r2;
```

But this should only be used if every object from Class `RineItem2` can be cast to `RineItem`.

A cast from `object` to `RineItem` would have to work every time! Hence you don't know what type is your object you're not allowed to:

```
object o = "bla bla";
RineItem r = (RineItem)o; // Not allowed! Will not work!
```